# Google Forms: Responce Validation: Regular Expression

Tags: regex, google-forms

I am trying make a Google Form. In the form there is a section for requested price. However the price must be divisible by 9, I was hoping to use a regular expression in the response validation. I have multiple formulas working together in the worksheet to show an alert if the price is not. But it would be very helpful if I could alert the user as they were filling out the form. I cannot seem to get the expression correct. Can someone give me some guidance, please!

Comment: Please provide samples of the code you've put together thus for to solve this problem. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: If you really really really really need a regex, you can build a finite automaton with 9 states labeled 0-8 and 10 transitions per state `m`, each labelled with a digit `c` going from `m` to the state labelled `(m + c) % 9`. Then, add a tenth state `S` that has 10 transitions labelled with some digit `c` going to `c % 9`. You now have an automaton that represents the division rule for 9. Use an algorithm from [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2016/how-to-convert-finite-automata-to-regular-expressions) to make a regex.